# why take the first hidden state for sequence classification (DistilBertForSequenceClassification) by HuggingFace

Tags: time-series, sequence, tensorflow2.0, text-classification, huggingface-transformers

In the last few layers of sequence classification by [HuggingFace](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/33d3072e1c54bcd235447b98c6dea1b4cb71234c/src/transformers/modeling_distilbert.py#L634), they took the first hidden state of the sequence length of the transformer output to be used for classification.

```
hidden_state = distilbert_output[0]  # (bs, seq_len, dim) <-- transformer output
pooled_output = hidden_state[:, 0]  # (bs, dim)           <-- first hidden state
pooled_output = self.pre_classifier(pooled_output)  # (bs, dim)
pooled_output = nn.ReLU()(pooled_output)  # (bs, dim)
pooled_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)  # (bs, dim)
logits = self.classifier(pooled_output)  # (bs, dim)
```

Is there any benefit to taking the first hidden state over the last, average, or even the use of a Flatten layer instead?

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is directly related to the way that BERT is trained. Specifically, I encourage you to have a look at the [original BERT paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.04805.pdf), in which the authors introduce the meaning of the `[CLS]` token:

> `[CLS]` is a special symbol added in front of every input example [...].

Specifically, it is used for classification purposes, and therefore the first and simplest choice for any fine-tuning for classification tasks. What your relevant code fragment is doing, is basically just extracting this `[CLS]` token.

Unfortunately, the DistilBERT documentation of Huggingface's library does not explicitly refer to this, but you rather have to check out their [BERT documentation](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/bert.html), where they also highlight some issues with the `[CLS]` token, analogous to your concerns:

> Alongside MLM, BERT was trained using a next sentence prediction (NSP)
> objective using the [CLS] token as a sequence approximate. The user
> may use this token (the first token in a sequence built with special
> tokens) to get a sequence prediction rather than a token prediction.
> However, averaging over the sequence may yield better results than
> using the [CLS] token.

Comment: +1. If averaging over the embeddings of the sequence could yield better results, why those authors didn't adopt this approach?

Comment: I presume that the alternative is more compute-intensive and therefore not worth the (maybe only marginal) gains.